# CentOS certificate check fails behind proxy

Tags: centos, wget, certificates

I am trying to install Tensorflow Serving on a CentOS-based container image behind a corporate proxy. However, I have issues running this `bazel` build command:

```
$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server
```

Result (extract):

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'upb':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/protocolbuffers/upb/archive/9effcbcb27f0a665f9f345030188c0b291e32482.tar.gz] to /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/upb/temp10914614927449415720/9effcbcb27f0a665f9f345030188c0b291e32482.tar.gz: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/protocolbuffers/upb/archive/9effcbcb27f0a665f9f345030188c0b291e32482.tar.gz] to /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/upb/temp10914614927449415720/9effcbcb27f0a665f9f345030188c0b291e32482.tar.gz: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR: no such package '@upb//bazel': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/protocolbuffers/upb/archive/9effcbcb27f0a665f9f345030188c0b291e32482.tar.gz] to /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/upb/temp10914614927449415720/9effcbcb27f0a665f9f345030188c0b291e32482.tar.gz: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I found that with other tools I also experience similar issues, such as with `wget`:

```
$ wget github.com
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2021-03-11 16:56:32--  https://github.com/
Resolving proxy.mycompany.com (proxy.mycompany.com)... 172.18.76.212
Connecting to proxy.mycompany.com (proxy.mycompany.com)|172.18.76.212|:8080... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘github.com’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘github.com’ doesn't have a known issuer.
```

Specifically, for `wget`, I can ignore these issues with `--no-check-certificate`, download the dependencies with `wget` that `bazel` cannot fetch and continue the build process. But I'd prefer to solve the root problem, if possible.

As far as I understand, the root cause is missing certificates. So, I tried to install them:

```
$ yum install ca-certificates
$ update-ca-trust force-enable
$ openssl x509 -outform der -in github-com.pem -out github.crt  # I used Firefox to download this PEM file
$ mv github.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/github.crt
$ update-ca-trust extract
```

I also synchronized the system clock with an NTP server.

After this procedure, the output of `bazel` and `wget` remained the same. Firefox offers me to download a certificate and certificate chain of github.com as PEM as well as these two from my company. Nothing of them worked.

What else can I try and how can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [workaround solution](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5741) for bazel build 'cacerts' issues, I feel.

In my case, I did as below,

```
bazel **--host_jvm_args="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261/jre/lib/security/cacerts"** build -c opt --cxxopt=--std=c++11 --config=android_arm //tensorflow/lite/c:tensorflowlite_c
```

GoodLuck!!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: This solution works after installing the certificates in Java's trust store with `keytool`.